# Python Script runs in IDLE Shell and Bash as .py not as .exe

Tags: python, string, dictionary, executable

I'm trying to find values in a dictionary, check if they meet a criteria (above a numerical limit) and remove the key:value pair from the dictionary. This works fine in IDLE Shell and Bash, but once I covert the file and try to run as an executable, gets stuck and throws an error code stating that a string can't be converted to a float. Program initiates, but gets hung up when the "limiter" is called on one of the dictionaries.

I've tried pyinstaller and changing .py to .command (mac) (chmod +x file.command, tried using int().

```
#brings str1 and str2 into single dictionary
def dictionizer(str1, str2):
  str1 = str1.strip().split('\n')
  str2 = str2.split('\n')
  str2 = filter(None, str2)
  d = dict(zip(str1, str2))
  return d

##brings dicitionaries together
def merge(d1, d2):
  merged = d1.copy()
  merged.update(d2)
  return merged

#synthesizes list of strings into dictionaries
d_burgers = dictionizer(burgers, burgers_kcal)
d_breakfast = dictionizer(breakfast, breakfast_kcal)
d_chicken = dictionizer(chicken, chicken_kcal)
d_salad = dictionizer(salad, salad_kcal)
d_fries = dictionizer(fries, fries_kcal)

#creates finds all values above/below limit, removes qualifying       key:value pairs
def limiter(d):
  for k,v in list(d.items()):
    if float(v) >= b_limit + 100:
      del d[k]
    if float(v) <= b_limit - 50:
      del d[k]
  return d

#asks for a kcal limit, divides that limit arbitrarily, creates limits for all meals
print('What is your kcal limit for the day?')
limit = float(input())
b_limit = limit*0.30 
l_limit = limit*0.35
d_limit = limit*0.35

#sets the original dict to the limited dict
d_breakfast = limiter(d_breakfast)
d_burgers = limiter(d_burgers)
d_chicken = limiter(d_chicken)
d_salad = limiter(d_salad)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/********/Desktop/*****/setup.command", line 68, in     <module>
    d_breakfast = limiter(d_breakfast)
  File "/Users/*******/Desktop/*****/setup.command", line 54, in  limiter
    if float(v) >= b_limit + 100:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
logout
```

I think I found some better solutions to some of the lines there to at least whittle down what could be preventing the conversion. And now it very specifically won't convert at a point which seems like it should:

```
def dictionizer(str1, str2): 
    str1 = str1.strip().split('\n') 
    str2 = str2.replace('\n', ',').split(',') 
    str2 = list(filter(None, str2)) 
    str2 = [float(i) for i in str2] d = dict(zip(str1, str2)) 
    return d
```

Still getting: 
     str2 = [float(i) for i in str2] 
     ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Why would it be unable to convert everything in str2 into a float? Tried integers, get:
    str2 = [int(i) for i in str2]
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

Try printing v inside the function: limiter, just before the if condition. Convert to .exe file with console enabled. Check for v values.

The error states that the value v is a string, and cannot be converted to flag.

Some of your dictionaries values are inconsistent.

Comment: I think I found some better solutions to some of the lines there to at least whittle down what could be preventing the conversion. And now it very specifically won't convert at a point which seems like it should:

    def dictionizer(str1, str2):
      str1 = str1.strip().split('\n')
      str2 = str2.replace('\n', ',').split(',')
      str2 = list(filter(None, str2))
      str2 = [float(i) for i in str2]
      d = dict(zip(str1, str2))
      return d

Still getting: 

    str2 = [float(i) for i in str2]
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: